# Output an Array in PHP , array inside an array

Tags: php, for-loop, foreach

I only want to output an array, first look at my code

CODE:

```
$shopping = array();
$shopping["john"] = "notebook1";
$shopping["john"] = "notebook2";
$shopping["doe"] = "notebook3";

echo '<pre>';
print_r($shopping);
echo '</pre>';
```

OUTPUT

```
    Array
(
    [john] => notebook2
    [doe] => notebook3
)
```

But I want my output to be like this:

```
    Array('john'=>array('notebook1','notebook2'),'doe'=>'notebook3');
```

How Can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just need to assign $shopping["john"] to an array.

```
$shopping["john"] = array("notebook1", "notebook2");
$shopping["doe"] = "notebook3";
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to add []= not just = try this :

```
$shopping = array();
$shopping["john"][] = "notebook1";
$shopping["john"][] = "notebook2";
$shopping["doe"][] = "notebook3";

echo '<pre>';
print_r($shopping);
echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, `$shopping["john"]` is a **String**.You need to declare it as an array. You can create your main array all in one:

```
$shopping = array(
    "john" => array(
        "notebook1",
        "notebook2"
    ),
    "doe" => "notebook3"
);
```

If using **PHP 5.4** you can use the [short array syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php):

```
$shopping = [
    "john" => [
        "notebook1",
        "notebook2"
    ],
    "doe" => "notebook3"
];
```

With this syntax you can use the shorthand to add an item to an array:

```
$shopping["john"][] = "notebook4";

/*
RESULT:
[john] => Array
    (
        [0] => notebook1
        [1] => notebook2
        [2] => notebook4
    )
*/
```